# How can I break my Cypher query to 2 subqueries?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to have a query that starts with 2 given nodes and for each of them takes the up to 5 related nodes (by relation R1) and then looks for shortestPath between those 10 nodes (5 from the 1st and 5 from the 2nd original nodes).

I can't manage to "break" my query into 2 parts, each one calculates the 5 nodes and then MATCH the path on both of them.

My query so far is:

```
MATCH (n1:MyNode {node_id:12345})-[:R1]-(r1:RelatedNode)
WITH r1 LIMIT 5
MATCH (n2:MyNode {node_id:98765})-[:R1]-(r2:RelatedNode)
WITH r1,r2 LIMIT 5
MATCH p=shortestPath( (r1)-[*1..10]-(r2) )
RETURN p
```

The problem is that the second subquery is not really separated from the first, and still carries on `r1`, which makes the `LIMIT` wrong.

I want to run the first part, then run the second part (with only `r2`), and only then after having `r1` and `r2` calculated separately, match the shortest path.  Can that be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you pelase write the two queries you want in pseudo code? just to know what you expect as result from each of your queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your requirement correctly. I assume you want to find the shortest path in between any of the first five neighbors of `n1` and `n2`.

I guess you have to pass through the limited result as a collection and `UNWIND` it later on:

```
MATCH (n1:MyNode {node_id:12345})-[:R1]-(r1:RelatedNode)
WITH r1 LIMIT 5
WITH collect(r1) as startNodes
MATCH (n2:MyNode {node_id:98765})-[:R1]-(r2:RelatedNode)
WITH r2, startNodes LIMIT 5
WITH collect(r2) as endNodes, startNodes
UNWIND startNodes as s UNWIND endNodes as e
MATCH p=shortestPath( (s)-[*1..10]-(e) )
RETURN p, length(p) ORDER BY length(p) ASC LIMIT 1
```

Be aware that the two `UNWIND` basically create a cross product. So you're calculated 5*5 = 25 shortest paths. Out of them we sort by length and pick the first one.

Comment: Thanks! UNWIND did the trick. I didn't know about it. A cross product is what I wanted.